# c++ srand works when I run the program but doesn't work in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb, srand

c++ srand works when I run the program but doesn't work in gdb.
I'm using Ubuntu logged into a terminal. 
Learning c++. 
My program runs as it is supposed to if I just execute it. But I really need to start learning to use the debugger. As I step thru the program the call to srand gives the following error.

```
12      srand(time(NULL));
(gdb) 
__srandom (x=1451559304) at random.c:210
210 random.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) 
211 in random.c
(gdb) 
210 in random.c
(gdb) Quit
```

Here is the first part of the program, it is pretty simple.

```
1 #include <iostream>
2 #include <cstdlib>
3 #include <ctime>
4 #include <string>
5 
6 using namespace std;
7 
8 
9 int main()
10 {       
11         int array_size=0;
12         srand(time(NULL));
13         cout<<"\n\nWhat size of an array would you like?\n";
14         cout<<": ";
15         cin>>array_size;
16         int my_array[array_size];
17         for (int i=0;i<array_size;i++)
18         {
19                 my_array[i]=(rand()%100)+1;
20         }
21         for(int i=0;i<array_size;i++)
22         {
23                 cout<<"\n"<<my_array[i];
24 
25         }
```

When compiling I use this line.

```
g++ -g main.cpp -o a
```

And when I start the debugger it use this.

```
gdb a
```

I would appreciate any help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Side note : Use an `std::vector` for a dynamically sized array.

Comment: It seems you have stepped *into* the `srand` function, which you should not do. Step *over* it. Learn the difference between the `step` and `next` GDB commands.

Comment: To elaborate on the error, when you step into the `srand` function the debugger will want to load the source file where the `srand` function was defined, since you don't have it you will get an error about it not being found. It's usually an error you can ignore for library or system files.

Comment: That"s Great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stepping into the standard library sources. Assuming you do HAVE the sources, you could set gdb up to find them with `dir` or `set directories`. But most people don't have the source for their C standard library - and unless you are actually trying to debug the standard library code itself, I'd suggest using the `n` (next) command instead of `s` (step) to step OVER the `srand`.

Note that the error you are getting is simply that gdb can't find the source file for `srand`. It will still step through the function eventually - but it will take some stepping, and without source code to view what it's doing, it's pretty pointless.